# Kinect and OpenNI sample code in C (aka not C++)

Tags: c, kinect, openni

Does anyone know of some sample code in C (not C++) along the lines of the Java/Processing code used in the projects given in "Making Things See"?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but here's something I found: https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiCRead/NiCRead.c

Apparently it's the same thing as [NiSimpleRead](http://openni.org/docs2/Tutorial/samples.html#nicread), but I'm not sure if that's what you want.